# Where can I find the standard discount curves for the standard CDS model?

Tags: cds

Where can I find the standard discount curves for the standard CDS model?

In particular I'm keen to see if ZAR is a supported currency yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the data [spec](http://www.cdsmodel.com/assets/cds-model/docs/Interest%20Rate%20Curve%20-%20XML%20Specifications.pdf), currencies published only include USD, GBP, EUR, JPY, CHF, CAD, AUD, NZD, SGD, and HKD.